# Role of Resistor in circuits mainly in analog electronic

Tags: resistors

Why do we use resistor as load?
And why their are different value when it made from same material

Comment: Is this a philosophical question? ... A resistor is a power dissipating unit, everything has resistivity.

Comment: A load where?  Why are there different values of capacitance when so many capacitors are made of the same material?  Extremely poor question.  Move to close.

Comment: Other components are used as loads; it depends on the application. Some loads are resistive, but not resistors.

Answer (score 1):

> And why their are different value when it made from same material

The material alone does not determine resistance, it only determines [resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity). Geometry combined with that gives resistance. Basically, resistance is directly proportional with the length \$\ell\$ of the resistor and with its resistivity \$\rho\$, but inversely proportional with its cross-sectional area \$A\$:

$$ R = \rho\;\frac{\ell}{A}$$

And resistors commonly used in electronics may look visually similar, but the resistive element does not actually have the same geometry for different resistor values. Details depend on the construction, but example if we have a [wirewound resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Wire_wound), there's thick core that's only used to hold a thin wire. The wire itself is the resistive element and it does have different thickness and length for different value resistors.

[image]

The same goes for film resistors, etc.

[image]

The ceramic substrate that you see there has huge resistance itself because of its much higher resitivity; for comparison Wikipedia gives 1.1×10<sup>-6</sup> resistivity for nichrome and 1.0×10<sup>11</sup> for glass. Since the substrate and the wire/film are [in parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Resistors_2), the total resistance is very well approximated by just that of the film/wire.

---

As for why use a resistor as a load, Chu answered it; it depends on the application, but resistors are cheap/common so often they are used as ["dummy" loads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_load) for testing (and not just in small electronic projects).