# Is resistance fundamental property of matter that conducts electricity?

Tags: resistors, resistance

My question is - Is resistance fundamental property of matter that conducts electricity?

Here's what I mean.

Let's take a wire that has 100 Ohm resistance (it's made from crappy metal with a lot of defects in it). If I send electricity through it, the electrons will experience 100 Ohm resistance because that's how the wire is. It's a bad quality wire with lot of resistance.

Now let's combine two 100 Ohm wires in parallel:

```
   ---100Ohm---
---|          |---
   ---100Ohm---
```

By doing this and applying resistor formula, we get that this new wire is only 50 Ohms in resistance!!

Somehow using two crappy wires and combining them we were able to create a "new" wire that has better conductivity properties!

Isn't resistance (and conductivity) properties of material?

I'd imagine 100 Ohms would be the lower limit for this wire NO MATTER HOW we combine wires (in circles or parallel or twisting etc). It's still the same crappy wire with 100 Ohm resistance.

How is that possible? My mind is bending.

Let's say we take world's crappiest material that has 1000000000000 Ohms of resistance (almost infinite). Now if we combine a billion pieces of this wire, will we get a superconductor that has no resistance?

How does it work? How is it possible?

Somehow by combining the same material with the same conductive electric properties we were able to decrease resistance.

Isn't resistance defined as fundamental property of matter? I'm puzzled how it was possible that by using same material we were able to achieve lower resistance.

Comment: This is just another way of stating your existing question of today [How is it possible that if I combine 100 Ohm resistors in different ways, I get \_LESS\_ resistance than original?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202031/how-is-it-possible-that-if-i-combine-100-ohm-resistors-in-different-ways-i-get).  Please take time to think about the questions you have already asked before posting more.  You might also want to look up the geometric component of the units of resistivity.

Comment: Also note that being crappy has nothing to do with any particular resistance value. For instance, platinum RTDs are made of extremely high-quality platinum wire, and 100 ohms is a standard value.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as two small streams allowing double the amount of water to flow back to the ocean from a rainstorm. That's pretty much the same thing going on except it's with electricity instead. If you make one giant stream, that would make it easier for the water to get back to the ocean. If you have a bunch of small streams, that also makes it easy for the water to get back, but if you just have one small stream from the mountain all the way back to the ocean, it's going to take all the water a long time to get back.

Answer (score 0):

Resistivity, not resistance, is a fundamental property of a chemical element. The resistivity of a material depends not only on the resistivity of the elements of which it is composed but also other factors like 1.how the elements are combined, alloy, chemical compound, mixture etc. 2.the homogeneity of the material. The resistance of an item like a piece of wire is determined by the resistivity and the size and shape of the wire.

Increasing the area that is available for current to flow through decreases the resistance. Increasing the distance that the current flows increases the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

*Resistivity* is a property of material that determines the resistance of a piece of that material.  The resistance of a wire is proportional to its length, and inversely proportional to its cross-sectional area.

For example, if the resistance of a 10 ft piece of wire with a cross-sectional area of 0.1 square inches is 10 ohms, 20 ft of the wire will be 20 ohms.  If we have a 10 ft piece of wire with a 0.2 square inch cross-section, it will have a resistance of 5 ohms - half the resistance of the 0.1 sq. in. wire.

Connecting two 10 ft pieces of the 0.1 sq in wire in parallel will give an effective cross-section area of 0.2 sq in, so the effective resistance of these two wires in parallel will be 5 ohms - same as the 0.2 sq in wire.

For your parallel resistor problem, *each* parallel resistor provides an *additional* path to carry currrent, so more current can flow, so the effective resistance is reduced.